# TinyMce fail while executing setContent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, serialization, tinymce-4

I am trying to use tinymce 4.7.1 (upgraded from my older tinymce 4.3.1). When I try to set the content of tinymce programmatically by calling method setContent, it is throwing following error:

```
Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined
```

After looking into the details of the error, I realize tinymce is expecting to have serialized class within it's tinymce.dom and in absence of this class it is unable to parse thus this error.

here's the snippet from tinymce

```
else {
          // Parse and serialize the html
          if (args.format !== 'raw') {
            content = new Serializer({
              validate: self.validate
            }, self.schema).serialize(
              self.parser.parse(content, { isRootContent: true }) //this line is throwing error
              );
          }
```

Comparing to the previous version (which used to work fine for me, version 4.3.1) there's no such dependency on serialize class.

Can someone suggest if I have to add more plugins or classes (which is not shipped in default package) in order to get my code working?

**My observation**: in an isolated prototype example when I run tinymce hosted on a cloud it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue partly with the advice given by @Michael. So in my case there were two issues.

1. Even though i had upgraded tinymce to use latest plugins and js files, i was still referring to older version of themes.min.js (this is because i am maintaining two diff verions of tinymce so that i can rollout this verion upgrade one by one to limited pages first) which was incompatible with new version. This results in inconsistent initialisation of tinymce editor. Once i fixed the source of theme file it initialised editor correctly
2. There were some instances where my tinymce editor was not loaded correctly and i was trying to execute setContent method to set content which results in error (as @Michael pointed out). So I moved setContent call to setup method exposed in objects which worked well.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please show some running code that shows how you are using `setContent()`?  I suspect you are trying to call it before the editor is fully initialized as the `init()` method is asynchronous.

The easiest way to make sure that you are waiting until the editor is fully initialized is to rely on the `init` event that the editor provides:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: '#myTextarea',
  ...
  ...
  setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('init', function () {
      editor.setContent('Using the on init stuff!');
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks @Michael for your response. when i try your suggested approach it still doesn't work. Looks like there's something else which is breaking the flow. About the code, i know it's really hard to guess about the main root cause of the issue without looking into the problem. So will try to share main execution flow of my directive.